# How does std::enabled_if work when enabling via a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, enable-if

I'm trying to understand how enable_if works and I understand almost everything except scenario #3 from

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

```
template<class T>
void destroy(T* t, 
         typename 
std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>::type* = 0) 
{
    std::cout << "destroying trivially destructible T\n";
}
```

if the expression in enable_if is true then partial template specialization is chosen, so if it is chosen:

1. why in enable_if is only condition without indicating second template parameter ?
2. What type is "type*" then ? void* ? if so, why ?
3. Why is it pointer ?

Comment: Imagine `typename 
std::enable_if<condition, void>::type * = nullptr` instead. You can write, e.g., `typename 
std::enable_if<condition, int>::type = 0` as well, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why in enable_if is only condition without indicating second template
>   parameter ?

Because the default `void` is just fine.

> What type is "type*" then ? void* ? if so, why ?

Yes, `::type` will be of type `void` if `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value == true`, this will result in `::type*` -> `void*`.

> Why is it pointer ?

So we can easily give it a default value of `0`.

---

All we're using `std::enable_if` for is to check for certain attributes (in this case checking if `T` is trivially destructible), if these result in `false` then we use it to create ill-formed code and thus eliminate this function from overload resolution.

If `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value == false` then `::type` will not exist and thus the code will be ill-formed. In SFINAE this is handy since this overload will then not be considered for resolution.