# enable_if on constructor

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I have the following code. I want to templatize class and class constructor on enum type. However, this code does not work? How can I achieve what I want?

```
#include < iostream >

#include < type_traits >

enum class MyType
{
    Positive,
    Negative
};

template < MyType T >

struct B {

    int val = 0;

    template<typename U = T>
    B(int n, typename std::enable_if<U==MyType::Positive>::type* = 0) : val(n) { };

    template<typename U = T>
    B(int n, typename std::enable_if<U==MyType::Negative>::type* = 0) : val(-n) { };
};

int main() {

    B<MyType::Positive> y(10);

    B<MyType::Negative> n(10);
}
```

Comment: Your first question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785354/how-does-stdenabled-if-work-when-enabling-via-a-parameter).  I've removed it so your question is just about getting the code you have running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template has a typename parameter, but you want your enum as parameter. Let's fix that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class MyType
{
    Positive,
    Negative
};

template <MyType T>
struct B {
    int val = 0;

    template<MyType U = T>
    B(int n, typename std::enable_if<U==MyType::Positive>::type* = 0) : val(n) { };

    template<MyType U = T>
    B(int n, typename std::enable_if<U==MyType::Negative>::type* = 0) : val(-n) { };
};

int main() {
    B<MyType::Positive> y(10);
    B<MyType::Negative> n(10);
}
```

Also, you can put the SFINAE expression inside the template parameters to unclutter the constructor parameters:

```
template<MyType U = T, typename std::enable_if<U == MyType::Positive, int>::type = 0>
B(int n) : val(n) { };

template<MyType U = T, typename std::enable_if<U == MyType::Negative, int>::type = 0>
B(int n) : val(-n) { };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to define the constructor outside of the struct definition, how do I specify the signiture? I tried

Comment: "template<MyType T, MyType U = T, typename std::enable_if<U == MyType::Positive, int>::type = 0>
B<T>::B(int n) : val(n) { };" and it fails

Comment: In the definition you must not put default values. Remove the `= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `T` is a *non-type template parameter*, so you cannot do `typename U = T` because you want `U`, a *type template parameter*, to default to `T`, which is a value from `MyType`.

The name `T` is very poorly chosen, which is probably why you made this mistake in the first place. Change `typename U = T` by `MyType U = T` and your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20, it would even be simpler with `requires`:

```
enum class MyType
{
    Positive,
    Negative
};

template <MyType E>
struct B
{
    int val = 0;

    B(int n) requires(E == MyType::Positive) : val(n) {}
    B(int n) requires(E == MyType::Negative) : val(-n) {}
};
```